# Error passing data between two ViewControllers when declaring the delegate within a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I’m trying to pass data between two ViewControllers with the initial call being made from a `UITabBarController`.

Here is what I’m doing. I’m using a class called `RaisedTabBarController` to add a custom button to a TabBarController, which works fine displaying the button, my issue is that when I tap the custom button I want it to take me to `FirstViewController` and then I want to pass data from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` via protocols but for some reason I’m getting an error that in my opinion doesn’t make any sense, it complains about a labels not being accessible within `SecondViewController`.

Here is the error:

> > fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the code…

#### Class ref from GitHub:

[RaisedTabBarController](https://github.com/itsKaynine/SwiftRaisedTab/blob/master/SwiftRaisedTab/RaisedTabBarController.swift)

#### TabBarController

Here I'm adding the custom button and making the call to go to FirstViewController

```
import UIKit
/// TabBarController subclasses RaisedTabBarController
class TabBarController: RaisedTabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Insert empty tab item at center index. In this case we have 5 tabs.
        self.insertEmptyTabItem("", atIndex: 2)
        // Raise the center button with image
        let img = UIImage(named: “myImage”)
        self.addRaisedButton(img, highlightImage: nil, offset: -10.0)
    }
    // Handler for raised button
    override func onRaisedButton(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        super.onRaisedButton(sender)
        // Go to FirstViewController
        let pvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “firstStoryBoardID”) as! FirstViewController
        /// Here, I’m not sure if this is the right way to tell that 
        /// SecondViewController will be the delegate not TabBarController, seem to work
        pvc.delegate = SecondViewController() as FirstViewControllerDelegate
        self.present(pvc, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

#### FirstViewController

From here I want to send data to SecondViewController

```
protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageData(greeting: String)
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func sendData() {
        self.delegate?.messageData(greeting: “Hello SecondViewController”)
    }
}
```

#### SecondViewController

Here I want to receive the data sent from FirstViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func messageData(greeting: String) {
        /// I do get message from FirstViewController
        print(" Message received from FirstViewController: \(greeting)")

        /// Here I get error, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        ///  I think it has something to do with the labelMessage not being accessible, but why? 
        labelMessage.text = greeting
    }
}
```

#### Any idea why am I getting the error in SecondViewController, why wouldn't labels be accessible if they are declared in SecondViewController?

Ideally I would like to be able to call method `onRaisedButton(_ sender: UIButton!)` directly from SecondViewController but without having to subclass RaisedTabBarController. I’m not usr if this would solve the error but I think this would make my code cleaner.

### EDIT: 06/19/2017 - Solved

The effect I was looking for can be done directly in XCode, in the storyboards. I stopped using the third party class (RaisedTabBarController), problem solved.

Comment: have you initialised second view controller ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where exactly would I initialize it. FYI - Passing data between FirstViewController and SecondViewController works if the protocol call is made directly from FirstViewController.

Answer (score 1):

This seems wrong.

```
pvc.delegate = SecondViewController() as FirstViewControllerDelegate
```

Try to instantiate the SecondViewController like you did for the first from storyboard.

```
let svc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “secondStoryBoardID”) as! SecondViewController
```

And then set the delegate to SecondViewController

```
pvc.delegate = svc
```

Comment: Make sure that SecondViewController conforms to the protocol.

Comment: Well, from TabBarController I want to go to FirstVC not SecondVC. FYI - I'm getting the data I'm expecting in SecondVC from FirstVC, I'm just getting an error about the label being nil.

Comment: You can try checking the outlet if it is connected properly in the storyboard. Otherwise make a break point in the view will appear method and see if other outlets you have set are nil or not, if all of them are nil or self is nil then you have to instantiate the controller from storyboard like I mentioned.